# GROMACS 4.6 in Ubuntu

Tags: software-center

Is Gromacs 4.6 available in the Ubuntu Software Center? I have had a look but I could not find it.

Please somebody lead me the latest version Gromacs 4.6.

Many Thanks

Comment: See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gromacs - the repository version is 4.5.5 for 12.04 or newer, and there doesn't seem to be a PPA. Debian seems to have 4.6 in their repositories however.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't available in SC but here is the website to download Gromacs 4.6: [Gromacs - Downloads](http://www.gromacs.org/Downloads)